Derived column from 2 dimensions in SSAS Cube
I have two dimension, say "Dimension1" and "Dimension2" in the SSAS cube. I would like to add a derived column in Dimension1 lets say col3 with the logic coalesce (Dimension1.col1, Dimension1.col2).
I tried creating a derived column with the coalesce or CASE when logic in the Dimension1 but its showing error when I'm referring Dimension1.col2 in the derivation. is it allowed in SSAS cube or not?
Dimension1



Id
Col1




100
Kevin


200
Tom


300
Null


400
Null



dimensions2



Id
Col2




100
peter


200
jerry


300
marek


400
pawel



Derived column Output col3



Id
col3




100
Kevin


200
Tom


300
Marek


400
Pawel




What's the error?

You can do this in DAX, but you shouldn't.  So do this in your ETL process, or the query that SSAS uses to load the dimensions.

In Power Query, create a column with "if ValueA <> null then ValueA else ValueB". There is a coalesce operator of ?? which would simplify that to "ValueA ?? ValueB", but the longer version is generally easier to support unless you have a dedicated team of Power Query wizards who know what ?? or coalesce means. ?? is hard to search!

It is either you do it in your SQL query :
COALESCE(Dimension1.Col1, Dimension2.Col2)

or using DAX as a calculated column :
Col3 = COALESCE(Dimension1[Col1], RELATED(Dimension2[Col2]))

Why it is not working ? Because you are simply referring to another column within the same dimension directly for calculated columns within the tabular mode which isn't supported in the way you're doing it.
